# Pytest pass overall if >50% of Selenium tests pass

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, testing, pytest

I am currently doing Selenium testing with Pytest. There will be around 10 tests, however, a user may only have 70-80% of the data available to test (which is fine).

Is there a way to then say, if 7/10 tests have passed, pass the overall pytest, but still show the failing tests

This will interact with a CI/CD pipeline, and it seems that if even 1 tests fails, that the Jenkins just sees red.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. A failing test is a failing test. If you don't have enough data for some tests, then don't run them at all.

Comment: You can configure Jenkins to regard a certain number of failing tests as an unstable instead of a failing build - so your build will be yellow instaed of red, if that is what you want.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen the post build section isn't available in the newer versions of Jenkins unfortunately https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49571

Comment: I'd agree with @pavelsaman - if you don't have preconditions fulfilled to run the test, just skip it. If you just want to continue running Jenkins pipeline when tests are failing, `pytest || true` is a common workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, if there isn't enough data for tests. Then don't run them.

I was able to find a database table which only contains the users with the relevant data. Now all tests are passing 100%.

Thanks everyone for the help.